# Disabling IPV6 firewall with IPV6 disabled

Tags: ipv6

Our router (Asus RT-AC68U) has been slowing down our speeds, up until I disabled the IPV6 firewall (Went from 250 to 380, which is the modem cap for now). We've always had IPV6 disabled on the router, but I was wondering if it poses any security risk by also disabling the IPV6 firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device cannot speak IPv6, then it is very unlikely that having an IPv6 firewall enabled would offer any protection.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is that once you add a device that uses IPv6, you won't have protection. Leaving the protection on covers you when you make changes to the network, and you don't have to remember that you turned a protection off.

If the router simply won't process IPv6 packets, then that's a layer of protection, until you turn it on to allow an IPv6 device.

How much of a risk that might be *to you* is something only you can determine.